# Why is my for loop not working properly when checking if a vector is sorted or not?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm trying to check if a vector is sorted or not with a for loop but it's not working properly

until I make a small change but the logic seem to be the same to me.

this is the code:

```
vector <int> is_list_sorted(vector <int> list_of_numbers){
   bool list_is_sorted = true; 
   for(int i = 0; i < list_of_numbers.size(); i++){
       if(list_of_number[i] > list_of_numbers[i + 1]){
           list_is_sorted = false; 
       }
   }
   
   return list_is_sorted; 
}
```

```
int main(){
   if(list_is_sorted(vector1){
      cout << "the list is sorted" << endl; 
   }
   else{
      cout << "the list is not sorted << endl; 
   }
  return 0;
}
```

I tested this function on three different vectors and the output is always the same "the list is

not sorted" until I make a small change in the actual function and instead of:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list_of_numbers.size(); i++){
       if(list_of_number[i] > list_of_numbers[i + 1]){
           list_is_sorted = false; 
       }
   }
```

I make it:

```
 for(int i = 1; i < list_of_numbers.size(); i++){
       if(list_of_number[i] < list_of_numbers[i - 1]){
           list_is_sorted = false; 
       }
   }
```

what's the bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < list_of_numbers.size(); i++)
```

then `list_of_numbers[i + 1]` will be out of bounds for the last element.

If you go out of bounds you will have *undefined behavior*.

A different solution would be to change the loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list_of_numbers.size() - 1; i++)
```

Then `i + 1` will not be an out of bounds index anymore.

---

On another note: As soon as you notice that the vector isn't sorted you can return `false` immediately. You don't need to check the remainder of the vector.

Comment: ahaa okej I understand. but why wasn't the second loop that started from 1 not out of bound. it worked properly

Comment: No, it wasn't. The second loop starts from `i=1`, so `i-1` is `0`.

Comment: oh yeah I see I see

Comment: not forgetting that your second sample might fail if the list is empty

Comment: @AlanBirtles would a simple check if the list is empty or not be enough or is there anything else I should change in the function itself?

Comment: A check for empty is not good enough: When you run the test you touch two elements, so if your list has 0 or 1 elements (not just 0) then you need to skip the test. However, you can do this test in the loop parameters. With `i=0; i<size` the loop is skipped on an empty list, with `i=0; i<size-1` or `i=1; i<size` the loop is skipped for lists with 0 or 1 elements. Of course, you then need to use `[i+1]` or `[i-1]` as appropriate for the loop parameters you choose, to avoid stepping out of bounds.

Comment: @sam the issue is that `size()` returns an unsigned number so when the list is empty `size() - 1` doesn't return `-1` it overflows to the maximum value of `size_t`